# Angular: Dynamic binding using ngModel to array of index

Tags: angular

Developing angular app for aptitude exam prepation
Got stuck in technical component.
I want to record user response on the question and store it in the array ***checkedOptions: string[] = [];*** 
Need help for this,
Bind user response to index of array

I'm not using ngFor here in this code. Every new question get loaded on click.

**technical.component.html**

```
<h3><span class="label label-warning" id="qid">{{no+1}}</span>{{ question }}</h3>
    <div class="quiz" id="quiz" data-toggle="buttons">
               <label class="element-animation1 btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span> <input type="radio" id="q_answer" name="q_answer" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="checkedOptions[no]">{{optionA}}</label>
               <label class="element-animation2 btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span> <input type="radio" id="q_answer" name="q_answer" [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="checkedOptions[no]">{{optionB}}</label>
               <label class="element-animation3 btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span> <input type="radio" id="q_answer" name="q_answer" [value]="3" [(ngModel)]="checkedOptions[no]">{{optionC}}</label>
               <label class="element-animation4 btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span> <input type="radio" id="q_answer" name="q_answer" [value]="4" [(ngModel)]="checkedOptions[no]">{{optionD}}</label>
    </div>
```

**technical.component.ts**

```
public checkedOptions: string[] = [];
public no: number;

//some code

setTimeout(() => {
      for (let index = 0; index < this.technicalService.questions.length; index++) {
        this.technicalService.technicalResponse.push(new Response(this.technicalService.questions[index].correctOption,this.checkedOptions[index]));
      }

      //send data to the server for marks calcualtion of module
      this.technicalService.calculateTechnicalMarks();

      console.log(this.technicalService.technicalResponse);

      console.log("Time over");



      //Tried to print this array out in the console
      for(let i=0; i<this.technicalService.questions.length; i++){
        console.log(this.checkedOptions[i]); //use i instead of 0
    }

      this.router.navigate(['/home']); 
      }, (this.commonUrl.communicationTime * 1000 * 60 + this.commonUrl.questionLoadinTime));
  }

//some code
```

**snip of console output**

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOaYD.png)

Comment: A doubt. How are you changing/updating question? And it would be really helpful if you create sample stackblitz example, to understand completely.

Comment: created two button **next** and **previous** and onclick event I'm changing questions and options.

Comment: What I think is. You should handle your save response logic in parent component. Your component should only handle rendering question and click of answer. On click of answer you  should `output` event to parent component. As parent already know which question is rendered, it should update response in your service.

Comment: this component know which question is rendered and it is stored in ```public no: number;``` this variable @Kenny